# Help with French translation

Tags: traduction

I'm working on a project that needs french translation.
Can you help me?

#### A little context

This page shows a report with events that happened during a period.

The text I need to translate is this: (in bold)

**Unjustified Major Events**
The total number of events that do not have a justification.

**Total Major Events**
The total of events in general.

**Data Entry Score**
The proportion of justified events.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a translation that I would suggest

**Unjustified Major Events** translated as "**Événements majeurs non justifiés**"

**Total Major Events** translated as "**Nombre total d'événements majeurs**"

**Data Entry Score**  translated as "**Pourcentage de données rentrées**"

Hope it can help you :D

Answer (score 0):

> Unjustified Major Events → Évènements majeurs sans justification

I put "without justification/sans justification" because "unjustified/injustifié" doesn't feel natural to me.

> Total Major Events → Total des évènements majeurs

Simple and transparent.

> Data Entry Score → Score de saisie des données

Not 100% sure this is the best translation, but it is a literal translation and gets the point across